# Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 255

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1, iis-8.5

I have been using this PC to develop ASP.net applications for over a year (v4) and everything runs fine. For some reason today when I try and load any project locally this message shows.

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 255

I have done extensive Googling and tried near on everything and nothing has worked. Some of the stuff I have tried;

- Restarted and repaired IIS 8.5
- Restarted the machine
- Created new application pools to the same settings as a working machine.
- Reinstalled Visual Studio 2010
- Checked the application settings and application pool settings

The only thing that  has changed lately is that there were some windows updates installed when I turned my machine on this morning and am unable to roll back to before hand as restore points were disabled.I am on Windows 8.1

I know this question has been posted before but none of the suggestions they posted seemed to work so was wondering if anybody has experienced this before and had luck in fixing this issue? any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but have you tried using a newer version of Visual Studio?

Comment: We have some applications on VS 2013 and this also gets the same error.

Comment: Try deleting all Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I have done and have tried again, sill no luck

Comment: If you create a brand new ASP.NET project do you also get the error? If not, try merging one of the projects. It might help you find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Have just tried on a new project and same error comes up. Merging didn't help either.

Comment: Does the application work if you use / debug with IIS Express instead of IIS 8.5?

Comment: Nope, Tried that too, Same issue with IIS express.

Comment: Are there further details in the Event Log? You could try booting in safe mode. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The event log shows an error in vbc.exe - Faulting module name: s\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120_CLR0400.dll!__crtGetFileInformationByHandle did a quick search but got real answers.  Thanks for your help so far @Greg. Looks like a complete reset and reinstall of OS and VS may have to be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, Not the best solution for most people but as I wanted to go to windows 10 at some point I installed the upgrade and now everything is working fine.

Figured the issue was with a windows update that went wrong and as restore points was turned off this was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

In My case i already Used :
HttpContext cnt = HttpContext.Current;
for use session and everything doomed , 
remove that and working fine 
but i believe its a bug because this line work on another version of IIS , i already test it too